# How do I copy over my old files from my Java Eclipse workspace into my new workspace?

Tags: java, eclipse, filesystems, workspace

I had to reinstall some things on my computer, eclipse being one of them. I took my workspace and made a folder out of it and left it on my desktop. I used Indigo last time, but I have to update some time, so I decided to upgrade to Juno. I set the default workspace to a new folder, eclipseWorkspace, and dragged all the files from my previous workspace into the new file (eclipseWorkspace). I also set the default workspace to eclipseWorkspace, but none of my old files show up in the navigator or pack explorer. I'm sure that this is just a small mistake that requires me deleting some file or something like that, but I've been at this for about an hour and I'm not really sure where to go from here. How do I get all of my old Java projects to my new workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use import into the new workspace...

Comment: ^Thanks. Sorry for the stupidly obvious question, but I've only been using eclipse for about a month, and I'm still not acquainted with all of it's menu features and such. Thanks, though. I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome, you should mark either answers as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to File --> Import, then select Existing Projects into Workspace.
You can then select the root directory of your workspace. Eclipse should do the rest for you.

Answer (score 0):

First use the import option for old projects.

If want to copy your old setting then copy to your new workspace:

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings
```